# Generating object-unique indexing for large amount of objects

Tags: python, list, dictionary, indexing, python-dataclasses

I hope you guys can lend me a hand with this one :)

I am trying to create python objects for a 3D software. These objects need to have a meaningful name like the following: **L_hello01_EXT** and are generated using some variables for each of the parts.

The number in it, however *(the 01)* should be automatically generated. The criteria for that would be that if an object with that same name already exists, increment the index by one until the generated name isn´t being used by any other object.

The problem is that I need to create about 20k of these or more so I need to find a way to figure out fast the latest available name while keeping the objects.

Right now I have tried 2 methods:

1. Creating an empty list and storing the names as they are being generated. Then checking `if` the name is `in` cette list. While the name is in the list, increase the index by one and try again.
2. Creating an empty set and add the names to it. To check if the node exists: copy the set, add the name of the node to it and comparing both set's length. If the copy is greater than the original, the name is new.

```py
class BasicNode:

    node_pool = set()

    def __init__(self, side: str, name: str, ihi: bool, **kwargs):
        """Initializes the NodeInfo object of the node, and generates a name for the instance and appends a
        the generated instance to the class' node_pool variable."""

        # Create NodeInfo instance using default params. For now it will only hold naming info.
        self._node_info = NodeInfo(side=side,
                                   inherited_name=name,
                                   ihi=ihi,
                                   **naming_kwargs)

        # Build the name of the node using _node_info obj
        self._node_info.generated_name = self.__get_first_available_name(self)

        # Append to list
        self.__class__.node_pool.add(str(self))

    @classmethod
    def __get_first_available_name(cls, basic_node_inst: "BasicNode"):
        node_info_obj = basic_node_inst._node_info

        node_info_obj.generated_name = cls.__build_name(node_info_obj.side,
                                                        node_info_obj.inherited_name,
                                                        node_info_obj.tag,
                                                        node_info_obj.count,
                                                        node_info_obj.suffix,
                                                        node_info_obj.extension)

        while objExists(basic_node_inst) is True:
            node_info_obj.count += 1
            node_info_obj.generated_name = cls.__build_name(node_info_obj.side,
                                                            node_info_obj.inherited_name,
                                                            node_info_obj.tag,
                                                            node_info_obj.count,
                                                            node_info_obj.suffix,
                                                            node_info_obj.extension)

        return node_info_obj.generated_name


def objExists(node_object: BasicNode) -> bool:

    incremented_set = node_object.__class__.node_pool.copy()
    incremented_set.add(str(node_object))

    if len(node_object.__class__.node_pool) == len(incremented_set):
        return True
    return False

# ==== DUNDER METHODS ===============================================

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self._node_info.generated_name)

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self._node_info.generated_name)
```

Any help is welocome :)

Ty!

Comment: Do you generate all these names in one go, or are you looking for solutions that can continue to generate names later? Where do you keep the names of all the other elements in that case?

Comment: I cannot understand how you came up with that set solution. That is so weird. You do know about `in`.

Comment: it sounds like you are asking about `dictionaries` in `python`.  Please reduce the code to the necessary parts to make the problem clear:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Any objection to only storing the latest number, and always increment by one? Like, a simple counter

Comment: @Grismar I am currently looking for a solution that generates the objects (with the names) in one go.

The names of the objects are an attribute on the NodeInfo object that gets generated and also the return values of the __repr__ and __str__ methods of the class (I forgot to add them in the example).

The names of all the objects get stored inside the class variable node_pool (a set). The last step of the constructor of BasicNode adds the str(self) to it.

Comment: @KellyBundy the thing is that I used originally used the `in` operator to check if the name was in a list (prior to making it a set).

However, the way I got the index was far too slow to be usable and the time it took to compute skyrocketed really fast when if I want to create more than 500 objects.

The `set` solution I tried was to see if I could compare the length of the original set and one where I tried to add the newly generated name. If the length of the new set was the same it would mean that the object existed and therefore the cound should be incremented by 1.

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues this would be good if all the names were using the same parameters to generate them but they actually require a few different ones (see this -> `node_info_obj.generated_name = cls.__build_name(node_info_obj.side, node_info_obj.inherited_name, node_info_obj.tag, node_info_obj.count, node_info_obj.suffix, node_info_obj.extension)`)

And I would like to see if the name matches with **any** name currently inside the class variable: `node_pool`.

Comment: Yeah I know what you did, it's just mind-blowing that you did that. Why not just check `in` on the `set` the absolutely exact same way as on the `list`? Fast membership checks (and what they bring) are pretty much *the* reason `set` exists in the first place.

Comment: I think you misunderstood @RodrigoRodrigues' suggestion - if you keep a single counter every time you add a number, for all elements (you'd need to use 5 digits instead of 2, for 20,000 objects, unless you use a numbering system like hexadecimal or alphanumeric), all numbered objects would be guaranteed to be unique, since they all contain a unique number, so there would be no need to check at all.

Comment: @Grismar I don't really understand how you would do that. How could you detect if the object already exists if you just keep the counter? You should be able to have a name like this:

`a = BasicNode(side="l", name="hello", ihi=False, generated_name="hello")` -> (returns `L_hello00_EXT`)

if you create another obj w/ the same args you should get -> `L_hello01_EXT` but if you used different arguments the new name's count should start with 00 -> `R_hand00_EXT`.

If it's not too much trouble could you show an example?

Comment: Imagine handing out passports, giving each a unique number, and instead of keeping a copy of every passport, you just keep the number you last used and add one every time you hand out a new passport. You don't need to check all the old passports to know you're creating a unique one - the old ones will all have lower numbers. The only thing you have to remember is what number you last used. Examples in answer below (both of single counter, or per-pattern counters).

Answer (score 1):

User @RodrigoRodrigues suggested just having a single counter for all instances, instead of a counter per specific pattern. You asked for an example, this is a simplified example:

```
class BasicNode:
    unique = 0

    def __init__(self, side: str, name: str, ihi: bool):
        # I'm having to guess what `ihi` even means here, you provide no info
        self.full_name = f'{side.upper()}_{name}{self.unique:05}_{"EXT" if ihi else "XYZ"}'
        self.__class__.unique += 1


nodes = [
    BasicNode('l', 'hello', True),
    BasicNode('l', 'hello', True),
    BasicNode('r', 'bye', True),
    BasicNode('r', 'bye', False),
    BasicNode('r', 'bye', False)
]

print(list(n.full_name for n in nodes))
```

Result:

```
['L_hello00000_EXT', 'L_hello00001_EXT', 'R_bye00002_EXT', 'R_bye00003_XYZ', 'R_bye00004_XYZ']
```

If you need to keep track of counts for specific patterns, you could just use a `dict` with the key being a tuple of the relevant fields:

```
from typing import Dict
from collections import defaultdict


class BasicNode:
    counters: Dict[tuple, int] = defaultdict(int)

    def __init__(self, side: str, name: str, ihi: bool):
        nr = self.counters[(side, name, ihi)]
        self.counters[(side, name, ihi)] += 1

        # now you may not need as many positions, maybe 2 is enough
        self.full_name = f'{side.upper()}_{name}{nr:02}_{"EXT" if ihi else "XYZ"}'


nodes = [
    BasicNode('l', 'hello', True),
    BasicNode('l', 'hello', True),
    BasicNode('r', 'bye', True),
    BasicNode('r', 'bye', False),
    BasicNode('r', 'bye', False)
]

print(list(n.full_name for n in nodes))
```

Result:

```
['L_hello00_EXT', 'L_hello01_EXT', 'R_bye00_EXT', 'R_bye00_XYZ', 'R_bye01_XYZ']
```

Of course you can add complications, but the basic idea would be the same: keep a dictionary of `tuple` to `int` to keep track of what combinations have been used before, and make their value a counter. In both examples, the counter (the `int` or the `dict`) are kept as *class attributes*, which allows you to remember the value between creation of instances.

Note: the typing isn't required, it's just there to make it clear how it works. It doesn't hurt - in Python 3.9+, you'd be able to just use `dict` without the `typing.Dict` import.

Note: the `__class__` in the first example is needed to avoid redefining `unique` on the instance, you want to assign to the class attribute, not an instance attribute. That's not needed with the `counters` dictionary, because it's only being accessed, not set.

Note: in case you're not familiar with `defaultdict`, it allows you to access a value that hasn't been added before - it will just add the default for the type, in this case an `int`, so it sets a new entry to 0 when first accessed. You could do this with some code yourself, but why not use what the libraries have to offer?

Comment: Why `defaultdict(int)` instead of `Counter`? The latter seems more natural to me for counting.

Comment: Although... speaking of *"use what the libraries have to offer"*... `defaultdict(count)` would take that [one step further](https://tio.run/##nVHBasMwDL37K0R2SAKhjO4yAruMbcedeuhWSkgTpRE4srEdtlD67ZntrqHHMZ1k6em9Z0lPrlf88KjNPHdGDeAmTXwEGrQyDl6ocSLWGyUlNo4U22uzxa4epWsXDDk0Tim5IBo1shOikbW18Fxbat5Vi6UAH7GHxpZRZOdGLbEAYreHp1vqLAJzEYd8HaqKmFxVZRZlV4AlzwjWmQK4Hq4p9VTCwXvJL2oh2Hhmxm8XJ1dXA7ssUFym42C@/1ULcQesvmBSIwz15HPnGbCF2vo3T6CVpbiUIvQPCGsgC8hqPPYLR5TrRimroOFNdOkpaK5GrdFk@bk6hcb5xKa8X/tX8rrdJEBdcAMoLUKy/fhMzqkQgv0GrefYRfplqVkq0wLSHqVUPtmYEfPiHxATIIcJ/wJ4q721PyDEXght/GkzSdZlfLOLThlgf3WI38rzef4B).

Comment: @KellyBundy `Counter` is a class for counting hashable objects, but here we're not counting in the sense of wanting to know the size of an existing collection, we're just keeping count, so an integer is the right choice. I agree that using `itertools.count` is nice, but it does little to reduce the amount of code to read, and it arguably makes it harder to read for someone new to the matter - without clear advantages. I would use it, because it avoids accidentally changing the counter in some way, but I felt it was a complication OP didn't need :)

Comment: Ok, I understand that objection to `itertools.count`. But I don't get your point about `Counter`. It's values *are* integers, too. And it would be the exact same code, except for the different import and creating `Counter()` instead of `defaultdict(int)`.

Comment: You're right, I misunderstood - one *could* replace `defaultdict(int)` with `Counter()` there. Since the `defaultdict` requires some explanation as well, that would probably have been the better choice - but I'm going to leave it and give you credit for the comments.